# Type conversion troubles in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

My entity framework returns an IQueryable with all elements but links lost when i create list object.
That object(list) need to compare user data with list data. If anyone can help me i'll been grateful! Here's  [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845441/there-is-an-error-with-linq-system-notsupportedexception)!

```
MapToBindingModel = title => new TitleBindingModel
{
    Id = title.Id,     
    //data     
    // type conversion when studio's data lost because tolist    
    Studios = title.Studios.Select(i => new StudioBindingModel() { Id = i.Id, StudioName = i.StudioName, FilteredName = i.FilteredName, ImageShiki = i.ImageShiki }).AsQueryable(),               
    Favorite = _applicationUser != null && _applicationUser.Favorite.Titles.Any(i=>i.Id == title.Id),

};

protected ApplicationUserManager UserManager => 
    Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
internal ApplicationUser _applicationUser;

[HttpGet]
[Route]
[EnableQuery]
[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll()
{
    _applicationUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    return Ok(Service.GetAll().ToList().AsQueryable().Select(MapToBindingModel));
}

   // Repository getall code
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of Service.GetAll()?

Comment: `ToList().AsQueryable()`? What exactly do you think that does? You should really read the basics of Entity Framework. You are getting the entire result set in memory just for projecting, which is a complete waste of resources

Comment: I was advised to do this, the link to that question is higher

Comment: So... what's exactly the problem in your current code? What are you expecting to happen that does not happen?

Comment: I get the answer "Studios": [], because of tolist () if I do not do it then the error that was before this
[ { "Studios": [], 
        "Favorite": false,  
        "Id": "73a39954-db06-46cf-b10b-a39679158733"   }
]

Comment: You could try to do `.GetAll().Include(x => x.Studios).ToList().AsQueryable().Select(MapToBindingModel)`

Comment: The data is lost when converting to tolist (). I do not need Include

Comment: All data comes, but collections disappear after tolist

Comment: What you advised does not work